# How to put 'dot' as separator on every i type in number format with regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I try to make some pattern if my user type on my input field it will be automaticly convert to this format 12.345.678.9.012.345, i try to make it on react but it seems not working, it's always stuck when i type it. here is my code below :

```
myPattern(e) {
const regex = /(?=(.{13}|.{10}|.{7}|.{6}|.{3})$)/g;
const result = e.target.value.replace(regex, '.');
e.target.value = result;}


render(){
    return (
        <InputText
           required
           label="Number"
           type="number"
           name="numbers"
           value={this.state.docNumber}
           onChange={this.onChange}
           onKeyPress={e => this.npwpPattern(e)}
        />
     )
}
```

Comment: there is npm package `MaskInput` i will suggest you to use that, instead of using regex to apply some pattern, check this: https://github.com/insin/react-maskedinput

Comment: Your regex is wrong. Can you give an example of what text the user types into the input field first? Is it `'123456789012345'` that you automatically want to turn in to `12.345.678.9.012.345` ?

Comment: @AndyRay they can input with any number with length 15, if we got '123456789012345' the number '1' it should be the first one.

Answer (score -1):

Use `this.setState` for controlled components, only use DOM methods to read.

```
this.setState({docNumber: result});
```